# Rails not loading assets on elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asset-pipeline, sprockets

As title, I put my rails app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

My EB config: 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.4.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)

eb deploy works fine.

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to the instance(s).
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Application update in progress on 1 instance. 0 out of 1 instance completed 
(running for 38 seconds).
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

But when I opend the web, [it showed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnbFU.png)

It seemed that Rails did not load assets. After googling similar topics, I found that why but I can not fix it.

My problem is the same as [Rails app not loading assets on elastic beanstalk aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896633/rails-app-not-loading-assets-on-elastic-beanstalk-aws)

While deploying, EB will execute `rake assets:precompile` then generating files according to your manifests under `public/assets`.
All assets files' name will be added MD5-fingerprinting, such as :

`application-33792387f876db5e0593b1aff357fb300ab2fad24f42d463f4010ac271abb6ae.js`

And there is a `.sprockets-manifest-md5hash.json` which seems not working to avoid handing the mapping requests back to Sprockets.

When I tried to access my static file, ex: /assets/picture.png, the status code is 404 not found.

`http://my_app/assets/picture.png (404 not found)
http://my_app/assets/picture-MD5hash.png (200 complete)`

But the first one should work if `.sprockets-manifest-MD5hash.json` works.

Here is my `/config/environments/production.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on a copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.

  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths["log"].first, 'daily') # 或 weekly,monthly

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is how I ended up fixing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285597/3033467

Answer (score 1):

follow steps:

1. Goto `config/environments/production.rb`

   `config.assets.compile = true`
2. Run command: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`
3. Then push all compiled files with menifest.

Comment: not worked for me. I also tried set assets.digest = false, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found that disabling js asset compression fixed everything.

In config/environments/production.rb comment out

```
#config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Answer (score -2):

run command: `eb setenv RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled` before deploy